# JavaDB/Hibernate/Swing autosort

Tags: java, hibernate, swing, derby, javadb

I have a Java swing application with Hibernate and network JavaDB/DerbyDB. There is a table which is like this in structure:

TestID QuestionID
T1234     Q1
T1234     Q2
T1234     Q3
T1234     Q4
..
..
T1234     Q10

where combination of TestID and QuestionID has been defined as the primary key. Whenever i add/insert a row with Test ID 'T1234' and QuestionID 'Q10', the record gets added immediately after the record containing QuestionID 'Q1'. Example:

TestID QuestionID
**T1234     Q1

T1234     Q10**

T1234     Q3
T1234     Q4

I don't want this to happen as this is causing me trouble while fetching the records. Could you please let me know what should i do to avoid this.

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: what problems do you have with fetching records? if you need to them to be sorted then you have to specify it in the select query

Comment: @user1041345 Is your code available by any chance Im trying to do a simailr thing myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, databases store records in an order which is not necessarily the same as the order in which they were inserted. Hence, now since I have to fetch records in the same order as I have entered them into the database, i make use of auto incrementing counter while making the insert and use the order by clause (on the counter) while fetching the records.

Answer (score 1):

Define your own type

```
class QuestionID implements Comparable<QuestionID> {…}
```

and use it in your `TableModel` instead of `String`. Let its constructor extract the numeric part of the `questionID` returned from the database, and let its `compareTo()` implementation examine just that number. The [`Value`](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/table) class is `JTableTest` is an example.

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas: (a) store QuestionID as 1, 10, 3, 4, etc., and add the 'Q' prefix in your application, or (b) store QuestionID with 0-padding, as in: Q001, Q010, Q003, Q004, etc.